# How to run a few commands and have the output emailed once a day?

Tags: shell-script, mailx

new person here.

I would like to run uptime and bdf and have the output emailed to me.

I have the mailx part down-

```
/usr/bin/mailx -s "daily_update" someguy@thisplace.com </home/daily_update
```

And I am ok with how to add it to the cron so it sends the email everyday at 8:00am.

Just not sure how to do the scripting part that captures the output of `uptime` and `bdf`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` sends email with any command output by default, either to the user specified by `MAILTO`, or to the owner (which requires local email delivery to work).

A crontab such as this should do the trick, no need to handle email specially:

```
MAILTO=someguy@example.com
0 8 * * * uptime
0 8 * * * bdf
```